# Problem removing duplicate files using awk

Tags: linux, awk, duplicates

Contents of part3.1.awk

```
{
current_line=$0
if (current_line!=prev)
{
    print $1 " -> " " -> " $5 " -> " $8
}
prev=$0
}
```

To get the list of processes, i run this in terminal. I want to get output with removed duplicates and sorted too.

> $ps -ef | awk -f part3.1.awk | sort

What wrong am i doing?

Comment: I want to implement it without using uniq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting the output from the awk script, when you want to be sorting the input.

```
$ps -ef | awk -f part3.1.awk | sort
```

should be

```
$ps -ef | sort | awk -f part 3.1.awk
```

But I should tell you that you don't need awk to remove duplicates.  `sort -u` will do this for you, as in

`ps -ef | sort -u`

Comment: sorry.. i wrote wrong.. i will edit my question.. 
My main aim is to remove the duplicates...

Comment: Yes, this should work.  The problem is that your awk script relies on all duplicates occurring consecutively.  This is why you need to sort BEFORE passing the values to awk, rather than after.

Comment: And it is still the case that `sort -u` will give you sorted values without duplicates.

Comment: Hopy crap.. I searched the manual of "sort" for "duplicate" but didnt find anything, so posted the question.. 
I got what i wanted.. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$ ps -ef | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Ok. i got it.. i can use "sort -u"

Comment: sort -u is fine, i tend to use uniq since the intention is clear even when the reader hasn't seen the command before.